GTK4: The main window is minimized after a GtkAlertDialog is generated by the save button
I am developing an application in C using GTK4 where a helper window (add_book_window) is opened from the main window to add books.
void on_add_book_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{   
    CoreWindow *win = CORE_WINDOW(user_data);

    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_resource("/org/gtk/coreapp/add_book_window.ui");
    GtkWidget *window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "add_book_window"));
    
    g_signal_connect(save_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_save_button_clicked), win);

    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(save_button), "title_entry", title_entry);
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(save_button), "author_entry", author_entry);
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(save_button), "isbn_entry", isbn_entry);

    //gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WINDOW(win)); 
    gtk_window_set_modal(GTK_WINDOW(window), TRUE);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));

    g_object_unref(builder);
}

The helper window contains text fields (GtkEntry) to enter the title, author and ISBN of the book. However , if I interact with the save book button, and close the auxiliary window, the main window is automatically minimized. If I don't generate an alert with the button, the problem does not occur.
During my new troubleshooting attempts I noticed that the problem is not with the 'save' button per se, but with the alerts generated by it:
    void show_alert(const char *message, GtkWindow *parent)
{
    GtkAlertDialog *alert = gtk_alert_dialog_new(message);    
    gtk_alert_dialog_choose(alert, parent, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

Another thing I noticed, using GTK_DEBUG to understand the window hierarchy, I notice that Gtk still recognizes my GtkAlertDialog as a GtkMessageDialog and therefore during debug the BUG does not occur.
In my version of GTK4, GtkMessageDialog is deprecated, so it is suggested that we use GtkAlertDialog, so the difference between them is the ancestors, GtkAlertDialog only inherits GObject.
My save button function:
void on_save_button_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    CoreWindow *win = CORE_WINDOW(user_data);
    GtkWidget *add_book_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_widget_get_ancestor(GTK_WIDGET(button),GTK_TYPE_WINDOW));

    GtkEntry *title_entry = GTK_ENTRY(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(button), "title_entry"));
    GtkEntry *author_entry = GTK_ENTRY(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(button), "author_entry"));
    GtkEntry *isbn_entry = GTK_ENTRY(g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(button), "isbn_entry"));

    const char *title = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(title_entry));
    const char *author = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(author_entry));
    const char *isbn = gtk_editable_get_text(GTK_EDITABLE(isbn_entry));
   
    if (!check_lenght_save_button(title, author, isbn))
    {   
        show_alert("Todos os campos são obrigatórios", GTK_WINDOW(add_book_window));
        return;
    }
    
    Book *new_book = book_new(title, author, isbn);
    win->books = g_list_append(win->books, new_book); 

    GtkWidget *list_item = gtk_label_new(new_book->title);
    gtk_list_box_insert(win->books_list, list_item, -1); 
    gtk_widget_set_visible(GTK_WIDGET(win->books_list), TRUE)

}

I'm using:
GCC: 14.1.0
GTK4: 4.14.4
WIN11 - Home
What could be causing the main window to minimize when closing the helper window after interacting with a GtkEntry, and how can I prevent this behavior?
Previously the warning signs were displayed with reference in the main window and the difficulty also occurred. Now my GtkAlertDialog (show_alert) references (add_book_window) and the problem persists.
I tried removing the transient_for signal and manually configuring the window closing, but the problem persists. I also added debug messages, but I couldn't identify the reason for the main window being minimized.
I hope I can solve this problem and understand the signal passed to the main window after clicking the save button.

In your case I would try to comment-out parts of button code, that may be the source of the issue and therefore bisect the problem. You have something that triggers the problem in here, as you stated "If I don't interact with the button, the problem does not occur".
I am not using GLib frequently enough, but it looks like you may not need to call g_object_unref on floating object, created by *_new_* constructor. At least that is what i find online: https://discourse.gnome.org/t/when-should-i-use-g-object-unref/3834/2
That may be a long-shot, but I hope it will help.

First of all, I would try the simple function:
void
gtk_alert_dialog_show (
  GtkAlertDialog* self,
  GtkWindow* parent
)

The documentation says:
"It is ok to pass NULL for the callback if the alert does not have more than one button. A simpler API for this case is gtk_alert_dialog_show()."
"This function is a simple version of gtk_alert_dialog_choose() intended for dialogs with a single button. If you want to cancel the dialog or if the alert has more than one button, you should use that function instead and provide it with a GCancellable or callback respectively."
Obviously, it is necessary to use a callback function.
For me, it worked like this:
   // Display the dialog asynchronously and wait for the user's response
        gtk_alert_dialog_choose(dialog, parent, NULL, on_dialog_response, user_data);


and then the function:
void
on_dialog_response(GObject* quelle,  GAsyncResult *res, gpointer user_data)
{
        GtkAlertDialog *dialog = GTK_ALERT_DIALOG(quelle);
        GError *err = NULL;

        int button = gtk_alert_dialog_choose_finish (dialog, res, &err);
...

}

